# How to add custom font to xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am tried to add custom fonts to xamarin forms

Here are my steps

1. added custom font into xamarin.ios project resource and make it as BundeledResource
   [image]

2.Then i added info.plist file record about custom font
Visual studio not support to do visually, because of that i did it opening info.plis from text editor as following

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Helvetica-LT-33-Thin-Extended.ttf</string>
</array>
```

(Luckily i am work in MAcbook with parallels and i can open info.plist from xcode in macos here is the output of that)
[image]

3. Then i added the following code to change font family

But this custom font change not work

```
<Label FontSize="18" Text="Accountholder" FontAttributes="Bold">
        <Label.FontFamily>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
               <On Platform="iOS" Value="Helvetica-LT-33-Thin-Extended" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

here is the output

[image]

**Any missing Step or missing work?**

Comment: @SushiHangover can you put correct name

Comment: Open it in macOS' Font Book to determine the correct name

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, it works, thanks and yes its duplicate